selecting element in xpath based on 2 conditions and not on the same node level

UPDATED:
I don't know the syntax to filter on two conditions with the below structure.
I need to select one single and specific  <a class="_1ufH4" href="ELEMENT of INTEREST"> within one of the nodes called <div class="_1rOLI _My0B">
ONLY WHEN both the below conditions are met:

<h2 class="_2MeiE">PARIS</h2>

<div class="_16U2O typography-h220">20:30</div>


<root>

    <div class="_13nA5">
    <section role="none" class="_29N96">
        <div class="SppyD">
            <div class="_2Bl6B">
                <img src="https://example" alt="" width="20" height="20">
                </div>

                <h2 class="_2MeiE">LONDON</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="_26Fte">


                <div class="_1rOLI _My0B">
                    <div class="_2VB9y">
                        <div class="_18IfB">
                            <div class="_3u6AO">
                                <a class="_1ufH4" href="ELEMENT of INTEREST">
                                    <div class="_2AdVd">
                                        <div class="Xi8qr">
                                            <div class="_16U2O typography-h220">14:30</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="_1rOLI _My0B">
                    <div class="_2VB9y">
                        <div class="_18IfB">
                            <div class="_3u6AO">
                                <a class="_1ufH4" href="ELEMENT of INTEREST">
                                    <div class="_2AdVd">
                                        <div class="Xi8qr">
                                            <div class="_16U2O typography-h220">15:30 2</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
      

              </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>




    <div class="_13nA5">
    <section role="none" class="_29N96">
        <div class="SppyD">
            <div class="_2Bl6B">
                <img src="https://example" alt="" width="20" height="20">
                </div>

                <h2 class="_2MeiE">PARIS</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="_26Fte">


                <div class="_1rOLI _My0B">
                    <div class="_2VB9y">
                        <div class="_18IfB">
                            <div class="_3u6AO">
                                <a class="_1ufH4" href="ELEMENT of INTEREST">
                                    <div class="_2AdVd">
                                        <div class="Xi8qr">
                                            <div class="_16U2O typography-h220">20:30</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="_1rOLI _My0B">
                    <div class="_2VB9y">
                        <div class="_18IfB">
                            <div class="_3u6AO">
                                <a class="_1ufH4" href="ELEMENT of INTEREST">
                                    <div class="_2AdVd">
                                        <div class="Xi8qr">
                                            <div class="_16U2O typography-h220">16:30</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
      

              </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

<root/>

I have come across 'preceed siblings' but I am lost on how to select the element of interest based on the position of the two conditions I have given you.

It is not clear what you are trying to select and what the selection criteria are.

Imagine that condition 2 and condition 1 can be numbers - I am trying to select   - the question is how do I select a specific   based on, for example, Condition 2 of that div node _16U2O typography-h220 = 3 and the other CONDITION 1 at the top of the page = 5.   Condition 1 changes across other siblings of the root node _13nA5 that have other values for condition 1 and 2.

Imagine that condition 2 and condition 1 can be numbers (or text)

Also, assume that condition 1 and condition 2 are all different values - that's maybe why the above wasn't clear. Apologies

Condition2 values are all different across all the nodes called 

Still not clear. If you mean to have CONDITION 1 and CONDITION 2 as placeholders and in that example they would actually have different values for CONDITION 2 instead of the same value, then update your example. And then identify which element you actually want to select. Without a better explanation and a minimum reproducible example it's much more difficult to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Apologies again, I have updated the whole thing and made it more factual. Hopefully, it should be clear now and thanks for your help.

Please, correct the failures in your xml example

what are the failures in the xml?

I would never depend on classnames that seems to have random strings, like 2MeiE and _16U2O. They mostly change over time or by each request. Therefore try to find out which parts of the html are not changing each regeust en go from there. I suppose your href ELEMENT of INTEREST is the thing you are trying to find and not static?

If I understand correctly
//section[contains(.,"PARIS")]//a[@class="_1ufH4" and contains (.//div,"20:30")]

You may be able to further customise the first contains argument in order to get more uniqueness

thank you this is very close but there doesn't seem to be an AND relationship between the first part "//section[contains(.,"PARIS")]" and the second part "//a[@class="_1ufH4" and contains (.//div,"20:30")]".  Only the last part "//a[@class="_1ufH4" and contains (.//div,"20:30")]" gets applied without taking account the first condition "//section[contains(.,"PARIS")]".

I have tried the above in a bigger xml and this just selects all the @class="_1ufH4" containing 20:30. The first part with Paris doesn't do anything

The XPath descendant axis could be used as follows
//section[descendant::h2[. = "PARIS" and @class="_2MeiE"]]/descendant::a[descendant::div[. = "20:30" and @class = "_16U2O typography-h220"]]

One way that explicitly encodes some of the structure, using forward looking expressions and some predicates:
/root/div/section[div/h2[@class="_2MeiE"] = "PARIS"]
  //div[@class="_1rOLI _My0B"]
    //a[
      @class="_1ufH4" and 
      @href="ELEMENT of INTEREST" and 
      ancestor::*[preceding-sibling::*[h2[@class="_2MeiE"] = "PARIS"] ] and
      .//div[@class="_16U2O typography-h220"] = "20:30"
    ]

A little more generic XPath:
//*[.//h2[@class="_2MeiE"] = "PARIS"]
  //div[@class="_1rOLI _My0B"]
    //a[
      @class="_1ufH4" and 
      @href="ELEMENT of INTEREST"] and 
      .//div[@class="_16U2O typography-h220"] = "20:30"
    ]

More generic, using ancestor:: and preceding-sibling:: axes:
//div[@class="_1rOLI _My0B"]
  //a[
    @class="_1ufH4" and 
    @href="ELEMENT of INTEREST" and 
    ancestor::*[preceding-sibling::*[h2[@class="_2MeiE"] = "PARIS"] ] and 
    .//div[@class="_16U2O typography-h220"] = "20:30"
  ]

